# Mount and external hard drive on an Amazon ec2 Ubuntu server

Tags: mount, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm using the amazon EC2 servers for the first time, so I'm sorry if i'm not understanding something obvious.

I alredy created and connected to an EC2 instance with a ssh connection. I'm trying to use it to run some heavy c++ code but I need to use some data in my external hard drive to do it.

There's anyway that I can connect my usb external disk to my ubuntu server withou copying the files?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing build into SSH that can do that as far as I know. You can however setup a SSH server on your computer, port-forward and then use sshfs to connect your computer's storage as a file system on the Amazon server.

Comment: I tried some tutorials and nothing work. do you have some site that explains the exact thing that you said?